# How does a webapp forward to another webapp?

Tags: java, redirect, web-applications, jetty, war

I have two static wars filled with help files served by a Jetty server and a root context war.

- **help.war**     - English help files
- **help_CS.war**  - Czech help files
- **ROOT.war**

  Based on the locale of the request, I want to divert a user to the language relevant to them.  i.e. user requests */help/index.htm* and as they are requesting from a Czech locale, they get */help_CS/index.htm*.  The idea is that language packs can be added as required without too much fuss.

  [I tried](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19294207/jetty-redirect-based-on-locale) adding a custom [RewriteHandler](http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/7.6.13.v20130916/apidocs/org/eclipse/jetty/rewrite/handler/RewriteHandler.html), referred to in Jetty.xml which grabs the locale from the [Request](http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/stable-7/apidocs/org/eclipse/jetty/server/Request.html) and either forwards or redirects on *handle()*.  Both complain as response codes have been sent by this point...somehow?!

  I tried a custom [Filter](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/Filter.html) in the web.xml of the ROOT.war which I couldn't get to match */help/** no matter what variation of the *url-pattern* I tried.

  I then added a reference to the same [Filter](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/Filter.html) as the last attempt into *WEB-INF/web.xml* to my help.war which would match and URLS could be generated but I can't rewrite the URL at this point because it is always prepended by */help/* so the URL with help replaced with help_CS ends up as *domain/help/help_CS/index.htm*.

  So my question.  How should/could this be done?

Comment: Use javascript for it. if(isCS) {window.location.href = hostname/help_CS}, where isCS boolean variable.

Comment: Good plan but I can't.  The help files are dynamically generated by some third party software that allows very little customization.  That would mean that if we one day have fifty languages the JavaScript would need to be hand entered for 50*n (n being number of languages) every time help is generated.

Comment: You are right. Store your help files in subdirectories in main web application. I think it rigth way.

Comment: Another good idea unaccessible to me. We distribute in wars and restructuring how all our help is built and deployed isn't an option :(

Comment: What about sneaking `/../` into the rewritten URL?

Comment: Forgot to mention I'd tried that too. Doesn't allow it. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So! After a few days of messing around with this I've found [something](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2690198/servlets-forwarding-to-a-resource-in-a-different-webapp) that feels a little hacky but it works.

I use my custom [Filter](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/Filter.html) then put it in *WEB_INF/web.xml* for each *help_XX.war* with an individual *servlet-mapping* (but otherwise identical) for each war file as so

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/help_CS</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Then inside the [Filter](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/Filter.html) I get the [ServletContext](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html) of the required war and forward using that, manually removing */help* from the request address like so

```
  @Override public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain)
                                throws IOException, ServletException
  {
    HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
    String requestAddress = request.getRequestURI();
    String country_code = req.getLocale().getCountry();

    if (requestAddress.contains("/help/")) 
    {
        ServletContext forwardContext = config.getServletContext().getContext("/help_" + country_code);

        forwardContext.getRequestDispatcher(requestAddress.replace("/help", "")).forward(req, res);
    } 
    else 
    {
        chain.doFilter(req, res);
    }
  }
```